# PHP code to read sent email from an Email Account

Tags: php, email

As part of my project I need to read sent email & received mail(inbox) from an email account.
I have managed to implement reading received mail(inbox)using the below code. it's working suessfully

```
set_time_limit(4000); 

// Connect to gmail

$imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'test@gmail.om';
$password = '*********';

// try to connect 
$inbox = imap_open($imapPath,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());


// search and get unseen emails, function will return email ids
//$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
 $emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "royal enfield"');
$output = '';
 if (is_array($emails) || is_object($emails))
{
foreach($emails as $mail) {
   $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$mail,0); 
    $headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$mail);

    $output .= '<b>Subject:- </b>'.$headerInfo->subject.'<br/><br/>';
    $output .= '<b>Toaddress:- </b>'.$headerInfo->toaddress.'<br/><br/>';
    $output .= '<b>Date:- </b>'.$headerInfo->date.'<br/><br/>';
    $output .= '<b>fromaddress:- </b>'.$headerInfo->fromaddress.'<br/><br/>';
    $output .= '<b>reply_toaddress:- </b>'.$headerInfo->reply_toaddress.'<br/><br/>';
    $output .= '<b>Status:- </b>'.$overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread'.'<br/><br/>';


        $emailStructure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$mail);

    if(!isset($emailStructure->parts)) {
         $output .= imap_body($inbox, $mail, FT_PEEK); 
    } else {
        //    
    }
   echo $output;

   $output = '';
}
}
}
// colse the connection
imap_expunge($inbox);
imap_close($inbox);
```

I hope someone will help me to read sent mail
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add exprected result and actual result. If there is an error, add it too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code to Read Sent Items from an Email Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870502/php-code-to-read-sent-items-from-an-email-account)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use another $imapPath in your code (str 5)

For Gmail it's **usualy** **'{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail'**

so it will be

```
$imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail';
```

If it doesn't help, try to use code below to get all your folders

```
$imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}';
$mail_con = imap_open($imapPath, $username, $password);
$mailboxes = imap_list($mail_con, $imapPath, '*');
print_r($mailboxes);
```

You will get somithing like this

```
Array
(
  [0] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}INBOX
  [1] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}Sended
  [2] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/All Mail
  [3] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Drafts
  [4] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Important
  [5] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail
  [6] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Spam
  [7] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Starred
  [8] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Trash
  ....
```

Any of it you can use as $imapPath

---

If your gmail is not in English, folder-name may be encoded. 
Here is code to get by 3 emails for each folder. It'll help you to found needed

```
<?php

set_time_limit(4000);

// Connect to gmail


$username = 'test@gmail.om';
$password = '*********';

$imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}';
$mail_con = imap_open($imapPath, $username, $password);
$mailboxes = imap_list($mail_con, $imapPath, '*');
//print_r($mailboxes);

foreach ($mailboxes as $imapPath) {
   echo "\n\n\n\n\n============. $imapPath";


// try to connect
    $inbox = imap_open($imapPath, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());


// search and get unseen emails, function will return email ids
//$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
    $emails = imap_search($inbox, '');
    $output = '';
    $count = 0;
    if (is_array($emails) || is_object($emails)) {
        foreach ($emails as $mail) {
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $mail, 0);
            $headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $mail);
            $output .= "\n\n\n";
            $output .= '<b>Subject:- </b>' . $headerInfo->subject . '<br/><br/>';
            $output .= '<b>Toaddress:- </b>' . $headerInfo->toaddress . '<br/><br/>';
            $output .= "\n" . '<b>Date:- </b>' . $headerInfo->date . '<br/><br/>';
            $output .= "\n" . '<b>fromaddress:- </b>' . $headerInfo->fromaddress . '<br/><br/>';
            $output .= '<b>reply_toaddress:- </b>' . $headerInfo->reply_toaddress . '<br/><br/>';
            $output .= '<b>Status:- </b>' . $overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread' . '<br/><br/>';


            $emailStructure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $mail);

            if (!isset($emailStructure->parts)) {
//            $output .= imap_body($inbox, $mail, FT_PEEK);
            } else {
                //
            }
            echo $output;

            $output = '';

            if ($count++ > 2) break;
        }
    }
}
// colse the connection
imap_expunge($inbox);
imap_close($inbox);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the sent email with the following code:

```
$mailboxes = array(
array(
    'label'     => 'domain.com',
    'enable'    => true,
    'mailbox'   => '{mail.domain.com:143/notls}INBOX.Sent',
    'username'  => 'mail@domain.com',
    'password'  => 'mypassword'
)
);
$stream = @imap_open($current_mailbox['mailbox'], $current_mailbox['username'], $current_mailbox['password']);
```

Comment: I tried this, it's not working anyway thank you very much.